# How to select numeric data of certain length

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to select numeric data that is greater than 5 bytes. I have entered the below but get an error of ERROR: Function LENGTH requires a character expression as argument 1. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
29         PROC SQL;
30            CREATE TABLE WORK.FILTER_FOR_FDRMASTER_DAILY__0000 AS
31            SELECT t1.Account_id_nr,
32                   t1.Predecessor_CC_SK,
33                   t1.Successor_CC_SK,
34                   t1.Related_CC_SK,
35                   t1.Original_CC_SK,
36                   t1.Predecessor_Argt_SK,
37                   t1.Successor_Argt_SK,
38                   t1.Predecessor_OK,
39                   t1.Successor_OK,
40                   t1.CHD_SSR_IN,
41                   t1.CHD_SYSTEM_BANK,
42                   t1.USAANR
43               FROM WORK.FILTER_FOR_FDRMASTER_DAILY_2 t1
44               WHERE t1.Successor_CC_SK NOT = . AND t1.CHD_SSR_IN = 'Y' AND t1.CHD_SYSTEM_BANK NOT BETWEEN '867700000100' AND
45                    '867700009500' AND LENGTH(t1.Successor_CC_SK) > '5'
46               ORDER BY t1.Successor_CC_SK;
```

Comment: The base issue seems to be that the LEN function only works on a string.  You could simply compare the value of the field to the appropriate numeric value that would produce the length that you are interested in.

Comment: What do mean by the length of a number?  Do mean the magnitude of the number instead?  `t1.Successor_CC_SK >= 100000`

Comment: is `t1.Successor_CC_SK` a numeric column? If so, are you trying to count the total number of digits and decimals? e.g. where 43 = length 2, 43.33 = length 5?

Comment: Yes so it is a column and it has credit card numbers but there are also numbers that are not and only 5 digits. I want to ultimately exclude those and only showing the numbers with over 5 digits should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with both credit card numbers and 5-digit numbers, let's assume that all of them could be stored in one of three formats:

```
Num:  1234567890123456
Char: 1234-5678-9012-3456
Char: 1234 5678 9012 3456
```

Let's start with the first case, which assumes that the variable is numeric. You want to exclude all 5-digit values. You can use [this trick](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/08/31/digits-in-integer.html) by Rick Wicklin to count the number of digits in an integer:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
         select number
         from have
         where ceil(log10(number+1)) > 5
    ;
quit;
```

For the second and third cases, they'll be stored as characters. You can count the number of numeric characters in a string using `countc()` with the `D` option.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
         select compress(number, ' -')
         from have
         where countc(number,'','D') > 5
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: That worked Stu!!! Thank you. The accounts are actually in the first format (Num:  1234567890123456) so Rick's trick worked. Is this +1 > just stating at least containing 1 digit?

Comment: I made a typo :) The +1 should have been within log10().